# Increasing the max concurrent file uploads on a LAMP server

Tags: php, linux, apache, upload, lamp

I have an issue where my client wants to be able to upload more than 2 large files at a time, and i was wondering if any of you have a solution to this, i'm pretty sure that it is a setting in either Apache or PHP.

Here is what the scenario, i have an upload form for videos with a max file size of 1024MB (1GB), so when a user uploads 1 file that is less than or equal to 1GB it works fine, then they open a new tab and upload another large file, but when they open up a 3rd tab of that form and try to Upload i Get a IO error from the form, so i assume either PHP or apache is limiting the max number of concurrent uploads to the server.

**Edit:**

When i use another computer with a totally separate internet connection (separate/different external IP) i can upload there as well, so it seems like a max concurrent upload per client/IP.

Comment: what specifically is the error?

Comment: Not that it should affect this, but what is the value of the ini setting `max_file_uploads`?

Comment: max_file_uploads is the number of total files per request (meaning items in one form) my uploader only uploads one file, the issue is when users open 3 tabs and try to upload 3 files in separate windows/tabs simultaneously.

Comment: i think it may be a max requests per client setting somewhere. i just can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

I think increasing the memory assigned to a php script can help you, I don't think this is the most appropriate solution but when i was having problem handling lot of big files, I increased the memory for the script. If you are developing this for a very busy site i don't recommend this method but as far as i know try increasing the memory.

```
     ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

for testing if you have -1
            instead of 128M the system will give unlimited memory to the script. You can use this to test if the problem is caused due to memory.

Comment: ok, i tries the memory limit increase (i also tried -1 so it would be unlimited) but it did not work.
if i use a seperate computer (separate External IP) it will also allow me to upload 2 files. so i'm pretty sure it's a connections per client issue, i just can't figure out where the limit is impossed.